# Initializing RNNCell

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having issues with using any child class of tensorflows RNNCell. According to the tensorflow source, the state for any RNNCell should be a tuple, however when I give it a tuple, it throws an error saying that it's trying to ask for the ndims attribute of the state tuple, which doesn't exist.

I am trying to create an LSTM where I can control each individual input.

This is the simplest code I can make, and even that has the same issue, so I hope that I am doing something wrong that can easily be fixed. This is the simple code:

```
    lstm_layer = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 64)
    initial_state = lstm_layer.zero_state(batch_size=1,dtype=tf.float32)
    initial_input = np.expand_dims(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),0)
    output_single, state_single = lstm_layer(inputs=initial_input,state=initial_state)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-1dcce10906e5> in <module>
      2 initial_state = lstm_layer.zero_state(batch_size=1,dtype=tf.float32)
      3 initial_input = np.expand_dims(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),0)
----> 4 output_single, state_single = lstm_layer(inputs=initial_input,state=initial_state)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope, *args, **kwargs)
    369     # method.  See the class docstring for more details.
    370     return base_layer.Layer.__call__(self, inputs, state, scope=scope,
--> 371                                      *args, **kwargs)
    372 
    373 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    528 
    529       # Actually call layer
--> 530       outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    531 
    532     if not context.executing_eagerly():

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    536       if not self.built:
    537         # Build layer if applicable (if the `build` method has been overridden).
--> 538         self._maybe_build(inputs)
    539         # We must set self.built since user defined build functions are not
    540         # constrained to set self.built.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
   1589     # Check input assumptions set before layer building, e.g. input rank.
   1590     input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(
-> 1591         self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
   1592     input_list = nest.flatten(inputs)
   1593     if input_list and self._dtype is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    107         spec.min_ndim is not None or
    108         spec.max_ndim is not None):
--> 109       if x.shape.ndims is None:
    110         raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +
    111                          layer_name + ' is incompatible with the layer: '

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndims'
```

It looks as though there is some base method that gets called for all layers in the keras API, but it doesn't work with tuples. However, I find it strange that this would be an issue that nobody has ever come against before. So I hope its just me making a mistake

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Tensorflow wasn't playing nicely with numpy in this case. Instead of

```
    initial_input = np.expand_dims(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),0)
```

I needed to give it

```
    initial_input = tf.expand_dims(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],dtype=np.float32),0)
```